# R: getting "inside" environments

Tags: r, namespaces

Given an `environment` object `e`:

```
> e
<environment: 0x10f0a6e98>
> class(e)
[1] "environment"
```

How do you access the variables inside the environment?

Just in case you're curious, I have found myself with this `environment` object. I didn't make it, a package in Bioconductor made it. You can make it, too, using these commands:

```
library('GEOquery')
eset <- getGEO("GSE4142")[[1]]
e <- assayData(eset)
```

Comment: any ideas for how I could find information like this on the net, without having to bother live people, would also be helpful. Searching for "R x" where x is whatever I'm stuck on today is consistently sucking. For example, the vanilla R documentation on environments doesn't help me all that much.

Comment: Start e.g at the rseek.org website for R-only websearches.

Comment: I second Dirk's suggestion -- be sure to check out the "support lists" tab in the rseek.org results, since much useful info can be gleaned from mailing lists.  For plain old google searches, throwing in "r-help" as a keyword is also likely to return archived mailing list results.  Alternatively, go to http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/ to search the mailing list archives directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls(e)` gives you names of objects in the environment and `e$name_of_object` gives you specified object (or `e[["a"]]`, or `get("a",e)`).

Comment: awesome. Thanks very much! Any ideas why an environment would be used over some other sort of container? Seems like a lot of effort to get the same effect as a list...

Comment: An environment is a reference - so using environments gives you mutable objects.