# Once again: Setting the environment within a function

Tags: r, function, plyr, environment

There are many discussions about scoping, environments and functions already. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234640/why-do-variable-lookups-in-the-body-of-function-a-take-values-from-the-global-en/23296536#23296536) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646402/using-functions-and-environments). However, I am not sure I have found a good solution to the following problem:

```
 df <- data.frame(id=rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=2), x=1:4)
 d <- -1
 myfun <- function(df, d){
          require(plyr)
          new.dat <- ddply(df, .(id), transform, x=x*d) 
          return(new.dat)}
 myfun(df, 1)
```

You can easily verify that the globally defined `d=-1` was used, instead of the `d=1` as provided in the argument. (If no globally defined `d` exists, then a `object not found` message is returned) The big question is now: how do I make the `d` argument to the function used instead of the globally defined `d`?

I was under the impression that the following should work:

```
      myfun2 <- function(df, d){
          here <- environment()
          new.dat <- ddply(df, .(id), transform, x=x*with(here,d)) 
          return(new.dat)}
      myfun2(df, 1)
```

It is my understanding that `with(here, d)` retrieves the object `d` from the environment `here`. So, the result should be `1`. An error is returned, though, saying

```
  Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
   invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'
```

I am not sure I understand why this does not work, and I would be happy if anyone could shed some light on this, or if you could provide alternative solutions. Note that wrapping the entire `ddply`-statement into `with(...)` does not seem to help either.

A solution that does work is to `attach` the current environment inside the function:

```
 myfun3 <- function(df, d){
   here <- environment()
   attach(here)
   new.dat <- ddply(df, .(id), transform, x=x*d) 
   detach(here)
   return(new.dat)
 }
```

but I don't like this solution since it works by masking the globally defined `d` with the local `d`, which I think is not very elegant.

Any comments / pointers are appreciated.

Comment: `new.dat <- ddply(df, .(id), function(x,d){x<-x*d}, d)` sort of works, but not quite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To wake up the lazy evaluation and be sure that you are using the local `d` argument, use `force`.  Add this line:

```
d <- force(d)
```

to the start of `myfun`.

---

OK, it seems that I misunderstood the problem.  In this case, the problem is that `ddply` has non-standard evaluation and only looks inside `df` for variables when applying transformations, so it doesn't see the local `d` even if you `force` it.  As Hadley pointed out, a you need to wrap `transform` insdie a call to `here`.

```
myfun <- function(df, d){
      require(plyr)
      new.dat <- ddply(df, .(id), here(transform), x=x*d) 
      return(new.dat)}
```

Minor unrelated code improvements:
Since you aren't doing anything with the case when `require` returns `FALSE`, you should swap it with `library`.
`mutate` is an improved <del>drop-in replacement for</del> alternative to `transform`.
You don't need the explicit `return`.

```
myfun <- function(df, d){
      library(plyr)
      ddply(df, .(id), here(mutate), x=x*d)}
```

Comment: `mutate` is **not** a drop-in replacement for `transform`; compare `transform(d, x=x*d, y=x)` and `mutate(d, x=x*d, y=x)`

Comment: Thanks! That was instructive. I have still not understood why the `with(here, d)`-solution does not work though. Providing a number instead of `d` works (obviously). Why is writing `with(here, d)` not the same thing? My understanding is that both should be equivalent from `ddply`'s perspective.

Comment: @coffeinjunky within `ddply`, the environment `here` isn't accessible; the error message is confusing because "here" is also the name of a plyr function.

Comment: Good point! Changing it to `here2` leads to an `object here2 not found` message. So, `ddply` evaluates everything in the global environment, i.e. `with(here2, d)` is evaluated in the global environment, but there, the local environment `here2` is not visible despite the explicit address? Is this what causes the issue?

Comment: yes – it's like addressing a postcard to someone on Mars or Tatooine; make it as specific as you want, the post office won't reach it.